Including an image/sprite/screenshot of Sonic in a dissertation?
I want to include an image of Sonic the Hedgehog in my dissertation; it is not part of the academic content in any way and is just a bit of fun.
I have a few questions:

Can I include a literal sprite from a Sonic game with a citation?
Can I include a screenshot of a sprite from a Sonic game (which would end up looking like option 1., except that it will be obtained differently)?
Can I draw my own rendition of Sonic or can I trace a sprite and then include it without a citation?

Thanks!

Have you wrapped up your dissertation already? If so, have you asked the copyright holder?

@Aruralreader I haven't, but I'm not sure how productive asking Sega will be. I'd rather first understand what would constitute acceptable/fair use in this context.

This seems to be a legal question without any special connection to Academia. You can probably ask on Law.SE if you keep it generic.

Very interesting question, but it might be better on [Law.SE]. Though, issues like this are generally fuzzy, so be prepared for an answer like "It's probably legal/not legal, but the only way to tell for sure is if this goes to trial, so you're probably better off not doing it." Let us know if you want us to migrate this post over there.

@cag51 Can't hurt trying---let's migrate it to Law. Thanks!
